# htaccess for multiple CMSes in nested directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Assume the following structure:

```
/main-cms/index.php
/main-cms/a-thing.php
/main-cms/foo/index.php
/main-cms/bar/another-cms/index.php
/main-cms/bar/another-cms/another-thing.php
```

I want to have a non-existent URL such as `https://example.com/main-cms/hello` be handled by the main CMS's index.php file and actual files served normally, such as `https://example.com/main-cms/a-thing.php` and `https://example.com/main-cms/foo/`.

The following .htaccess works fine for this:

```
RewriteBase /main-cms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I also have another CMS in a sub-sub-directory of the main one, which has its own .htaccess file and rules which allow that other CMS to manage its own part of the site. Requests to `https://example.com/main-cms/bar/another-cms/*` are handled by that other CMS .htaccess without the main one interfering.

Now how do I get requests to `https://example.com/main-cms/bar/` and `https://example.com/main-cms/bar/baz` be handled by the main CMS .htaccess (which points to `/main-cms/index.php`)? I get a 404 with the above code because the `bar` directory exists but there is no index page in `/main-cms/bar/`. Removing the `!-d` conditional will break requests to `/main-cms/foo/`.

Can this only be solved with a third .htaccess in the `/main-cms/bar/` directory to manually redirect or is there some condition/rule magic that will work in the main .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't need the `bar` directory at all. Move the nested CMS up a level. You'll need to ignore requests to the nested CMS in the main one, so put this rule first:

```
RewriteCond ^another-cms/ - [L]
```

In the nested one, set

```
RewriteBase /main-cms/another-cms/
```

What's in the web root? That's where I'd expect your main CMS to be. If it's empty like `bar`, do the same thing to it.

Comment: My example is an oversimplification of the problem which is migrating a massive site with multiple self-service applications (different non-traditional CMSes) to a new web CMS to handle most of the traditional static content which resides among those other CMSes. Moving directories around would break 20+ years of established links. While it's certainly doable, I'd prefer to maintain existing structures without a huge web of redirects.